# optimisation of curl request

Tags: php, curl

i'm developing a task report with wrike and i would like to know if it's possible to make it faster. I'm not confortable with curl, I'm not use to use it. All help will welcome :).

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = "Authorization: bearer ".$_COOKIE["wrike_token"];
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    foreach($folderArray as $currentFolder){

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.wrike.com/api/v3/folders/".$currentFolder->id."/tasks?completedDate={'start':'2016-10-11T00:01:00Z','end':'2016-10-11T23:59:00Z'}");
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        $result = json_decode($result);

        if(!empty($result->data)){
            foreach($result->data as $currentTask){
                echo $currentFolder->title." : ".$currentTask->title."<br>";
            }
        }
        if (curl_errno($ch)) {
            echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
        }                   
    }       
    curl_close ($ch);`
```

Comment: i think everything should be inside the foreach

Comment: no, because i did that before and it was worst, before, with all in the foreach the script was executed in 3m. now 45s.

Comment: Did you try to use multi_curl?

Comment: I tried also but i don't understand how it work.

Comment: make what faster? The development of the reports? the curl requests? wrike? Also, why do you think "it" is slow? Any numbers to base that assumption on?

Comment: the curl requests ^^. I tried an another way , put all in the foreach, it took 3min around to finish, with this exemple it take 45 secondes, but i'm wondering if there is a better way to be faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use https://github.com/marcushat/RollingCurlX which makes parallel cURL request and speed the fetching much better than doing sequential fetching.

Comment: i just try with that, but it doesn't work as well as thought, maybe i did something wrong, can you give me an exemple ?

Comment: This is how I usually use it:

Comment: $RCX = new RollingCurlX(10);
    foreach($links as $link){
        $link = trim($link);
        $options = [CURLOPT_FAILONERROR=>false,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST=>false,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER=>false,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER =>true,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true];
        $RCX->addRequest($link, null, 'callback_functn', null, $options, null);      
    }
    $RCX->execute();

Comment: after some minutes i made it work, but the problem it's i don't get all the list, i think it's because it's async. Or maybe i did wrong ? I mean, when i choose a period within many days, i get 1 task or sometimes 4 tasks, i'm suppose to get more. That why i think it's because it's async.

Answer (score 0):

Use [PHP request](https://github.com/rmccue/Requests) library will make your work easier:

Example:

```
$headers = array('Authorization' => 'bearer '.$_COOKIE["wrike_token"]);
$options = array('completedDate'=>"{'start':'2016-10-11T00:01:00Z','end':'2016-10-11T23:59:00Z'}");
$url = 'https://www.wrike.com/api/v3/folders/'.$currentFolder->id.'/tasks';
$request = Requests::get($url, $headers, $options);
```